# Asp.net java script date picker in child page not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, master-pages

i have created 1 master page 
and 1 child page 
in child page i want to add java script date picker control 
but its not working 
if i write code on other page without master page it working correctly ... please help

here is child page code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default123.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" Title="Untitled Page" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="jsDatePick_ltr.min.css" />
<!-- 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="jsDatePick_ltr.css" />
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsDatePick.min.1.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        new JsDatePick({
            useMode: 2,
            target: "TextBox1",
            dateFormat: "%m-%d-%Y",
            day:5,                      
            month:9,
            year:2006,
            yearsRange:[1970,2050],
            limitToToday:false,
            cellColorScheme:"beige",
            imgPath:"img/",
            weekStartDay:1  
        });
    };
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>

 1. List item
```

Comment: inspect the source, and find the link to jsDatePick script.
if you click it, does it show you the code?
if not, its to do with the location of the datepick js file

Comment: i have dragged this link directly from solution explorer...

Comment: inspect the source on the browser, then follow my steps

Comment: run the project. inspect the source in the browser (right click, view source).  find the link to the datepick js.  click it

Comment: hey if i dragg normal html control like 
<input id"text1" type"text">
 then it works
but not on asp control
<asp:TextBox ID="inputField" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
nw what should i do ???